# isImeVisible Causes State Loss

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to observe the state of keyboard visibility in my chat app to scroll the lazy column containing my messages to the bottom when the keyboard appears. For that I am storing `WindowInsets.isImeVisible` like so:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ChatScreen(viewModel: ChatScreenViewModel = ChatScreenViewModel()) {

    val messages = viewModel.messageListState
    val listState = viewModel.messageListScrollState
    val keyboardVisibility = WindowInsets.isImeVisible


        Column(.....)
```

and here are the ViewModel properties for context:

```
class ChatScreenViewModel: ViewModel() {

    val messageListScrollState = LazyListState()
    val textFieldState = mutableStateOf("")
    val messageListState = mutableStateListOf<String>(
            "dummy message 1",
            "dummy message 2",
            "dummy message 3",
            "dummy message 4"
        )
```

The problem is that whenever the `isImeVisible` is triggered (e.g., I tap on the TextField, keyboard appears, I type something, then hide the keyboard) all the states including `textFieldState` and `messageListState` are reset to their original values and lose their updated values. Even holding the `isImeVisible` value inside a variable seems to cause the issue and things only go back to normal when I completely remove it from my code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the ViewModel instantiation method to the one below seems to have fixed the issue:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel

fun ChatScreen(viewModel: ChatScreenViewModel = viewModel())
```